# Writing a subquery to display records in a grid

Tags: subquery, acumatica

I have two DAC's POReceipt, and and POReceiptLine. POReceiptLine containts a field called MfrPartNbr.

I want the user to be able to lookup all the POReceipts where the POReceiptLine.MfrPartNbr is equal to an entered value.

The SQL would be
    SELECT *
FROM dbo.POReceipt
WHERE POReceipt.ReceiptNbr IN
(
    SELECT ReceiptNbr
    FROM dbo.POReceiptLine
    WHERE MfrPartNbr  = 'MY_ENTERED_PART_NBR'
)

Any idea how to write the BQL Statement for this?

Comment: Some of the information like Receipt Type, ReceiptNbr, Vendor are available in POReceiptLine table, i mean, if you need little information you can use POReceiptLine table to get the data.

Comment: The point of this functionality is to see the POReceipts that have a line with a certain part number. I can't to join the tables together in this situation.

Comment: With Inner Join I'd think it would work. You can have the join optional too with the Or clause when the filter value is null.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, an inner join won't work in this case because you will receive the same POReceipt multiple times (once for each POReceiptLine). The following BQL query shows how you can get the desired results using a sub query. If mfrPartNbr is an extension field, then replace POReceiptLine.mfrPartNbr with the correct extension name (e.g. POReceiptLineExtension.mfrPartNbr).

```
PXSelect<POReceipt, Where<Exists<
                                Select<POReceiptLine,
                                Where<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<POReceipt.receiptNbr>,
                                    And<POReceiptLine.mfrPartNbr, Equal<Required<POReceiptLine.mfrPartNbr>>>>>>>>.Select(this, "MY_ENTERED_PART_NBR");
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to leave this answer, could you please update it to include a description of what you are doing?